# Vanity nameserver problems

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

After creating a nameserver subdomain named *1/2/3.buzztera.gr* with the help from a [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-vanity-or-branded-nameservers-with-digitalocean-cloud-servers) tutorial and creating glue records, I changed my nameservers to point to ns1/2/3.buzztera.gr from the registrar but this [test](http://www.webdnstools.com/dnstools/check-domain-results) says

> One or more name servers is not authoritative for this domain (or did not respond in time).

and

ns1.buzztera.gr : no nameserver

ns2.buzztera.gr : no nameserver

ns3.buzztera.gr : no nameserver

what else do i need to do ?

My current setup is

**Glue Records :**

ns1.buzztera.gr A (digital ocean ns1.digitalocean.com ip)

ns2.buzztera.gr A (digital ocean ns2.digitalocean.com ip)

ns3.buzztera.gr A (digital ocean ns3.digitalocean.com ip)

**DNS Settings (from DO)**

ns1.buzztera.gr NS

ns2.buzztera.gr NS

ns3.buzztera.gr NS

ns1.buzztera.gr A (digital ocean ns1.digitalocean.com ip)

ns2.buzztera.gr A (digital ocean ns2.digitalocean.com ip)

ns3.buzztera.gr A (digital ocean ns3.digitalocean.com ip)

**Registar nameserver:**

ns1.buzztera.gr

ns2.buzztera.gr

ns3.buzztera.gr

Comment: Please post the domain name, it makes helping to solve DNS problems so much easier

Comment: ok, its buzztera.gr. I will modify my question then.

Answer (score 5):

You missed this bit from the guide

> **For example:
>
>   (Do not forget the trailing dots)**

If you do a DNS query for `ns1.buzztera.gr` no results are returned however if you do a query for `ns1.buzztera.gr.buzztera.gr.` you get the IP of the `ns1.digitalocean.com`

By not adding the trailing dot the domain is applied to the record to create `ns1.buzztera.gr.buzztera.gr.` not `ns1.buzztera.gr.` go back and add the dot and the rest "should" work*

*Unless there other issues that fixing this will reveal

Comment: The NS does have a dot in the end.  buzztera.gr. 1800 IN NS ns1.buzztera.gr.
buzztera.gr. 1800 IN NS ns2.buzztera.gr.
buzztera.gr. 1800 IN NS ns3.buzztera.gr.

Comment: @user1919915 something somewhere doesn't because that is the exact reason this happens

Comment: Do A records require a dot? The only NS entries are those 3

Comment: @user1919915 yes

Comment: http://pastebin.com/MHpQUKu6 zone file as generated by digital ocean, anything wrong there?

Comment: @user1919915 Look at the A records, they are `buzztera.gr.buzztera.gr.` thats not right